# Javascript send message to objective-c in Mac cocoa application

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview

I'm fairly new to objective-C so please don't assume I know stuff because I probably won't :).

I have a cocoa application for Mac (not iOS) with a webview. In the webview there is a site which acts as a mini messaging client. When a message is received, I would like javascript to notify objective-c that a message has been received... and objective-c will then run some code such as create a growl popup.

I have looked at [WebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on the Apple Developer website, however I'm not quite sure how to implement it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the reference document "Calling Objective-C Methods From Javascript" ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215-BBCBFJCD))

Basically, to summarize it, you have to explicitly expose your Objective-C classes to the javascript scripting environment. The `WebScripting` informal protocol is the one you want to implement for your custom object to be exposed to be able to do just this.

Once the object you want to expose (e.g. your "Notification object") to javascript implements `+ (BOOL)isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:(SEL)aSelector;` and `+ (BOOL)isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:(const char *)name;` the controller/delegate of your webview should now make the object available to the javascript.

For instance, in the **Frame Load Delegate** of your webView instance:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didClearWindowObject:(WebScriptObject *)windowObject forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
     // Create the Obj-C object you want JS to be able to access
     CustomNotificationCenter *noteCenter = [CustomNotificationCenter sharedNotificationCenter];
     // Get the script object that corresponds to "window" in JS
     id win = [sender windowScriptObject];
     // Add our noteCenter as a property of "window" called "customNotifications"
     [win setValue:noteCenter forKey:@"customNotifications"];
}
```

And if you've done everything correctly, you should be able to use your Objective-C object in Javascript. For instance, if you've exposed a method named "printNotification:" for your `noteCenter`, in Javascript this should work:

```
function messageReceived(messageText) {
     window.customNotifications.printNotification_("Notification!" + messageText);
}
```

And of course you would use Growl to show the notification in your Custom Obj-C object and the implementation of `printNotification`. (If you're on Mountain Lion the new Notification Center is amazing, too). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have a few problems with *CustomNotificationCenter* because I'm not sure how to implement it.  I added this to my AppDelegate.h:    - (void)webView:(WebView *)webView didClearWindowObject:(WebScriptObject *)windowObject forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;    and added your code to the AppDelegate.m, but it gives me an error of *use of undeclared identifier 'note center'*

Comment: @SebastianRuiz Oh - "CustomNotificationCenter" is an example (nonexistant) class that I used for the sake of example code. In your case you would create your *own* class, give it functionality to integrate with Growl to send notifications, and then expose it to Javascript the same way I exposed the pretend-class "CustomNotificationCenter". If you need help doing that feel free to post another question!

Comment: I'm running Mountain Lion ;) so I should be able to use the built in notification center (or Hiss with Growl). I'm not quite sure how to do what you said. Especially the integration. I would love it if you could post an example. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @SebastianRuiz Ok - can you give me a day or two, when I find time to do so? Thanks

Comment: Yes the web app is in my control. Thanks for helping me out here - I owe you one ;).